# Send some data from front end window to electron browser window

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to send an object from front end window to electron's end. 
I tried this:

html:

```
const ipcRender = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
ipcRender.send('test', { test: null});
```

node:

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('test', (event, data) => {
  console.log(true);
  console.log(data);
});
```

and didn't see anything in console. What can be wrong? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, but if it isn't correct please comment it.
So instead of using "mainWindo.webContents" in Node, must be used "ipcMain" what imports from electron:

```
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');

ipcMain.on('test', (event, data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: That seems to be the way to go,  the explanation in the API docs would agree with your approach!

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main